# How to change the background color of a div on 2nd page once the link from 1st page is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Once the **change color** link is clicked i need to redirect to 
page2.html with a background color change in the particular div using 
javascript.

page1.html

```
<a href="page2.html id="page1">Change color</a>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="page2>
<h1>color change</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you only changing the background color on the click event? If so you would not need to redirect to another page using javascript

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do here. You load a `page2.html` and after loadingit you want ot change the background color of specific `DIV` from what to what? Why can't you just set the background color using CSS, as usual? How should teh change be visible, if you change the color right after loading? And: "i need to redirect" well, that's done by the browser, if the user clicks on the link. No need for further redirects.

Comment: first: you miss some quotes :)

when you load a different html... why can't you set the layout in this file (page2.html) ???

or do you use iframe or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can overide the first pages background with a new background from the current page

Comment: set body{background-color:/*the color here*/} of page2.html, it's very basic but works. it over rides the style from page1.